# Reference the current DOM element from inside event handler functions (pickadate.js)

Tags: javascript, pickadate

So I'm using http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/ and I'm trying to reference a date object in the DOM from within any of the pickadate event handlers.

For example I want to be able to say:

```
onClose: function() {
    var $this = ?; // <-- How do I define $this?
    $this.fadeOut();
}
```

Question:

How do you refer to the current DOM element from inside one of these event handler functions?

Note:

```
this, $(this) and $this don't seem to work :-(
```

Code:

```
var dates = $('.dates');

dates.pickadate({
    today: t,
    format: f,
    clear: false,
    min: min,
    max: max,
    selectYears: sy,
    selectMonths: sm,
    firstDay: fd,
    formatSubmit: f2,
    hiddenSuffix: s,

    onClose: function() {
        var $this = ?; // <-- How do I define $this?
        $this.fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Comment: can you add your html and js code?

Comment: Mmm... I found this `Within scope of all six of these events, this refers to the picker.` at the end of this page http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
onClose: function() {
    this.trigger().$node.fadeOut()
}
```

Comment: You can also write "debugger" statement in the first line of your function and using "chrome dev tools" to achieve better solution:
onClose: function() {
    debugger;
    this.trigger().$node.fadeOut()
}

Answer (score 1):

Based on the returned object, I suspect that what you are looking for is:

```
onClose: function() {
    var $this = this.$holder;
    $this.fadeOut();
}
```

Comment: You're definitely on to something there. this.$root.parent().hide() successfully hides the parent container of the pickadate element. The same for this.$holder.parent().parent().hide();

Comment: So what you are saying is that this.$root is actually what you were looking for? Meaning, in datepicker.js events, this = this.$root? If you figured it out maybe you can post the answer to the question yourself ;)